# No responsive page when redirected from facebook

Tags: html, css

I'm encountering a problem with responsiveness at my site https://zaplata.sk
When I try to access a webpage from browser on my smartphone, the website is full responsive. But when I try to open it from link from messenger, it's showing something like PC version wrapped into size of mobile phone.

here i'm posting screenshots from both cases.

[Accessed from smartphone browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2rAy.png)

[Accesed from redirect link from messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgxou.png)

Comment: It's just one URL, right?  How are you making the page responsive (media queries, browser detection, etc.?)

Comment: Are you getting the same problem with all messengers or any particular one?

Comment: I'm using SiteOrigin Pagebuilder to make webpage responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have added some icons in classic webpage for PC resolutions in menu.
But, i haven't it hiden in responsive state, so i created class in CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site_logos {display: none;}
}
```

and applied it via div

```
<div class="site_logos">
            <p align="right">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/zaplata.sk" target="_blank"><img style="margin : 1.5px 20px" src="https://zaplata.sk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fb_logo.png" width="33px"/></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/zaplata.sk/" target="_blank"><img style="margin : 1.5px 100px 0px 0px" src="https://zaplata.sk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/instagram.png" width="33px"/></a>
            </p></div>
```

and everything seems to work now :)